# How to place text on the same line in HTML?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, localhost

For my geography class in school we are making presentations on different countries and one of the options was a website. I know basic html but not a lot about the design and display aspect of it. Right now I've been having a lot of trouble getting text on the same line as you see on many websites. my code currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Swedish Political Geography</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <font face="verdana" size=“10”>Swedish Political Geography</font>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <ul><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Borders</font></ul>
            <ul><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Government</font></ul>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also been having trouble linking other files to this page. If you could help with that, it would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I've been trying for that:

```
<a href="borders.html">Borders</a>
```

I should mention that I have been using a localhost server to test my code and that is how I will ultimately present my project.

EDIT: To clarify, I'd like Swedish Political Geography, Borders, and Government all to be on the same line.

Comment: For start it must be <a href="borders.html">Borders</a> not <a heref="borders.html">Borders</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need a little bit of CSS for this solution. I’ll start with that.

If you have all HTML files in the directory, go ahead and create a CSS file named `index.css` or whatever you like, as long as the extension is CSS. Inside the `<head></head>` of each `.html` file put this link (changing the name of your CSS file if you didn’t use `index.css`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
```

Regarding your HTML, the `<ul></ul>` elements are really meant to contain lists with each item being defined with a `<li></li>` item, even if there is only one item. Knowing that, it should look a bit more like this:

```
<font face="verdana" size=“10”>Swedish Political Geography</font>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Borders</font></li>
  <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Government</font></li>
</ul>
```

`<ul>` and `<li>` elements are block level elements, meaning they will take up 100% of the available width. We want to change those to `inline-block` elements, which brings them inline with text but still gives you the ability to treat them a bit like block-level elements.

For that, drop this into your CSS file:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

… and for the `<li>`:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

It should be very close now, but you’ll notice the bullets from the list are still hanging around. Let’s remove those:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Adding `list-style-type: none;` tells the `<li>` not to display any kind of decorative feature.

You should now have a continuous line of text!

Example:

```html
<font face="verdana" size=“10”>Swedish Political Geography</font>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Borders</font></li>
  <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Government</font></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

ul - is a **block** element, you need to turn it to **inline** element

> display: inline;

in stylesheet just like this (or inside your css-file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Swedish Political Geography</title>
            <style>
                ul.navigation {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 4px;
                }
                ul.navigation li {
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 5px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <font face="verdana" size=“10”>Swedish Political Geography</font>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Borders</font></li>
            <li><font face="verdana" size=“10”>Government</font></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wanna all to be on the same line - add `display: inline;` into `ul.navigation block`